# Which one is more appropriate to use?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense

"I've never been so relaxed as I have been when jogging."

"I've never been so relaxed as I was when jogging."

"I was never so relaxed as I have been when jogging."

First one sounds the most formal and idiomatic one but I'd like to have your opinions as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence the repetition of 'i've never been' and 'have been' is redundant I would say, the second sentence reads better.

"I've never been so relaxed as I was when jogging."

However I would change the word order slightly like so:

> "I've never been so relaxed as when I was jogging."

As it makes the meaning slightly easier to parse for the reader.

Comment: I like this one "I've never been so relaxed as when I was jogging." sounds English to me. "I've never been more relaxed than when I was jogging."

Answer (score 0):

I think each sentence is actually saying something different, and it will depend on the context.

- *"I've never been so relaxed as I have been when jogging,"* suggests
  that at one point in your life when you were jogging, you were more
  relaxed than you've ever been before. A general way of saying jogging
  allows you to relax. Consider "I'm most relaxed when I jog," instead.
- *"I've never been so relaxed as I was when jogging,"* I think is
  different. Now "as I was when jogging" begs the question of *when*
  you were jogging. E.g. "I've never been so relaxed as I was when
  jogging [just now | yesterday]". It's related to a specific event.
- *"I was never so relaxed as I have been when jogging,"* I don't like this but I can't explain exactly why - it reads as: "I was most relaxed as I have been when jogging" and makes no sense.